# Review completed but the question still shows close votes; edit action isn't shown in review UI

Tags: bug, review-queues, vote-to-close

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9012865 shows "review completed" with 3 for and 3 against votes (strangely, it doesn't show my edit invoked from the review interface).

But, when I open the question normally, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755535/change-parameter-constraint-in-an-inherited-generic-method, it shows "4 close votes" - despite the fact that the close review is complete so they should have vanished. (and, if you noticed, there's 4, not 3 of them)

Which information is correct? What's up with this contradiction? Any why the "Edit" action isn't shown in the review UI as it is in "suggested edits"?

Comment: Review <> close. There is no contradiction. Close votes have nothing to do with review votes. The first has to do with votes to close, while the latter have to do with reviews. The two are not the same thing.

Comment: @KenWhite But, close votes do count the same as the "close" choice in review, don't they? They even have exactly the same interface. And the same number of votes is required...

Comment: @KenWhite ... not to mention that 1)when I browse the close reason selection UI, the number of "already cast" votes and their distribution matches what I see when I click the "close" link. 2)when I click "close" after reviewing, it says "you have already voted".

Comment: @DanielNugent Wrong as well! When I have reviewed an item but the review is not complete, on revisiting, it says _"You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed."_

Comment: All in all, it looks like the case of a reviewer taking the "Edit" option isn't handled correctly.

Comment: If the info in this thread is still accurate, choosing Edit from the close votes review queue will remove it from the queue  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work  That might explain the Review Completed message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, relevant SE meta references: [how Close Votes work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question), [how Review works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).
The focus of this investigation is how the two mechanisms are connected.

Close votes are distinct from close review votes, although the two notions are closely connected. Identical UI makes this even more confusing

- **When a user flags a question for closure / casts the initial close vote**

  - The question goes into the Close queue
  - If the user has the [close privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), it also registers a close vote with the stated reason

    - this will show up whenever the close reason selection UI is shown
    - regardless of whether the user chose "close" or "flag" link (so, for such users, the two are identical as far as closure is concerned)
  - If the user doesn't have the privilege (and thus can only flag), it only sets the suggested close reason for the review item
- **When further close votes are cast**

  - close reason selection UI shows as "previous votes"
- **When review actions are taken to close**

  - review actions include close votes as an unavoidable component
  - close reason selection UI shows as "previous votes"
- **When an "Edit" is chosen and submitted from the Review UI**

  - An Edit vote is registered in Review results
  - Review is instantly complete with "keep open" result (see below for what it means)
- **When the review is complete with consensus for close**
  Which means: accumulate 5 votes (or a decisive vote) towards closure, regardless of their origin

  - the question is put on hold
  - close votes disappear
  - review is marked complete, its results can still be viewed, including all review actions taken (but no actions taken outside of review, such as close votes cast directly on a question, or flags raised)
  - close reason is selected by majority from all votes, unless there are majority is a custom off-topic reason and multiple custom off-topic reasons are selected, in which case all will be shown
- **When the review is complete with consensus for keep open**

  - review is marked complete, its results can still be viewed, including all review actions taken
  - existing close votes do not disappear

    - but start [aging away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting)
    - if 5 close votes - both "old" and "new" - are accumulated

      - the question is immediately closed as usual
    - when another close vote is cast

      - a new, empty, Close Votes review queue entry is created, which will show all existing close votes in the reason UI but begins with no actions taken in its history

Comment: Ah, there we go. Votes to close a question outside the review queue, *including any initial vote that starts that review*, are not shown in the review entry at all.

Comment: Also, a question with a review ended with Leave Open can still be closed by close votes accumulated outside of the queue; any votes cast will start a new review entry as needed unless they finish closing the question. (That is, a question can have multiple review entries in succession; there will never be more than one current at a time, though.) [Current aging rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting).

Comment: Most close reviews, on SO at least, are I think started by *flags*, not votes. On ELL I have on many occasions observed an **in**equality... and I've even specifically traced that to either a) some particular person voting with a custom reason (so I know they VtC but they don't show up in review) or b) my own votes outside the review (which 2k allows me to see in history later).

Comment: @NathanTuggy sorry, I meant, the observed equality in the number and distribution of "previous votes" in _"close reason selection"_ UI in both cases. Which votes are shown there? And how do they correspond to "proposed close reasons so far" field in Review UI?

Comment: To save you time, could you just edit the answer, fixing what's wrong and filling in the gaps? I added the last concerns as "???"s as well.

Comment: Okay; it appears that, for this to be useful for future readers, the general mechanism overview should be moved to another question. You already addressed the matter of this particular case by providing explanation and, for the items where this proved insufficient, basically stating: "this is by design". What exactly this "design" is turns out to warrant a separate entry.

Comment: OK, I think I've figured out the last remaining confusion, having to do with the difference between close reason selection UI (which is the same everywhere) and review history shown after the review finishes (which only captures actions taken in the queue).

Comment: Hmm... so, close review votes add to close votes but not vice versa... And accumulating 5 happily ignores all the opposing ones. Which essentially makes the system biased towards closure - that, I didn't want to believe "before I see it". Thank you very much, Nathan. Too bad I can only upvote&accept your explanations once.

Answer (score 2):

Close votes can be cast outside of the review queue (and are in such cases not shown in the queue entry once it's complete: they're not part of the review). In fact, in this case, that's (probably) what actually triggered the review in the first place: someone cast a vote and a review entry was created accordingly; the question carried its first close vote in, collected three more for a total of four, then the review entry was closed out (by editing), so the queue will no longer direct close-vote-capable users at it. Close votes will age away one by one if there's been enough (100, last I checked) views on the question and enough time since the last flag or vote cast on that question. Every fresh vote or flag added will trigger another review entry if there's no active one.

A question may be closed entirely outside of the review queue, or entirely inside it: close votes are equally effective either way. The queue just automates focusing an existing ability on questions that are likely to need it. So it's incorrect to think in terms of "this question is X far from being closed, per the review entry"; rather, the number of current close votes is the only way to tell.

Note that the semantics of the <kbd>Edit</kbd> option are basically this: "This question does not need to be closed, **and I will edit it to make that clear.**" If that's *not* what you meant, you should not have chosen that option.

<strike>I don't know why the review entry doesn't show your edit.</strike> It does on other sites. (I just checked.) The review entry doesn't show your edit because your edit was completed after someone else had voted <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> enough to end the review. (Three review actions that select that will stop focusing that question. Once a question is closed, by any means, that will also end any associated review entries.)

Comment: It wouldn't show his edit because the review was already completed (3 leave open == done) by the time he submitted it.

Comment: @Shog9: Of course, I don't know why I didn't catch that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy So, you are saying that the question isn't "1 step from being closed" despite showing 4 close votes?

Comment: @NathanTuggy And, you didn't address the 2nd question: why 4 vs 3? The last close vote was cast after the review completed?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I am not saying that, and have updated to make that a little more abundantly clear. I actually did address the second question, though; reread the first paragraph, which explains that the first close vote was probably cast before the review began, and started it instead of a flag.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "vote cast before the review began" doesn't make sense. If the user who cast a vote/flagged had review rights, it should've registered as a review close vote as well; if they didn't have the rights, it shouldn't have registered as a vote at all ([note that vote numbers are typically equal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300624/review-completed-but-the-question-still-shows-close-votes-edit-action-isnt-sho/300805?noredirect=1#comment227890_300624)).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: It makes perfect sense, and that is exactly how it works. **You can vote to close without the review queue ever getting involved.** Your mistake is assuming the queue is primary; it isn't. It only comes in when someone has already flagged the question or voted to close it. (Note: I have been using my close-vote privileges on ELL for a while now, in and out of review.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy how can the review be not involved? Here, in black and white: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work  _"Questions with active close votes or close flags show up in the close queue"._ Sure, a question may be closed before anyone hitting it in review, but this doesn't make any difference - otherwise, vote numbers would very seldom be equal.

Comment: Okay, I'll write an answer myself on how the system appears to work - this way, it'll become clear where the information bits are missing.

Comment: [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300851/648265)