# The Community vs Meta Community

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

I am a "normalish" user of Stack Overflow.  I come here mostly to get answers to my questions and I love it.  (I occasionally post answers, but usually find that my expertise is not specialized or quick enough to get many answers out.)

As a normalish user, I have been watching a bit bemused by all the recent goings on in `The Community vs Stack Exchange Inc.`

I have been amazed by the display of callous disregard by Stack Exchange Inc. toward its community as shown in the Meta sites.  Especially considering that the community is the reason for the success of the company.  And is the only real path into the future as well.

As I read the goings on, I have been astounded that owners of Stack Overflow have not seen fit to step in and "right the ship".  In the end, it is their company (at least until an IPO happens).  They could stop it all if they so chose.

Then it hit me.

They have been convinced that "The Community" does not equal "The Meta Community".  To them "The Community" is something else that is more or less doing OK.

This separation of groups in the eyes of Stack Exchange Inc. was further confirmed by the opening sentence of the [CEO's recent post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going?cb=1):

> Hello members of the Meta community

Not "hello members of the community", but Meta community.

I don't know any statistics on number of Meta participants, but I am guessing (based on the general indifference displayed by Stack Exchange's leadership) that Meta constitutes little more than a vocal minority of what it sees as its community.

In fact, the more I look at things, I think that the sole goal of Stack Exchange Inc. in regards to the Meta Community is to keep them from poisoning "The Community" with its problems.  That is why the Community Managers get in trouble when they "[fail to control" the Meta Community](https://twitter.com/shog9/status/1217543503867076608)

If this is true, I see two extremes in the path forward for active meta users:

**1. Burn it Down**
This one essentially boils down to proving them right.  Meaning that Meta makes such a fuss that Stack Overflow fails (or at least is significantly reduced).

I see this one happening by spreading the word to the larger community.  Poisoning them with Meta's toxicity (as Stack Exchange Inc. would see it).

This option would be the most satisfying to those who are angered by Stack Exchange's poor choices.  It would be even more satisfying if a competitor could come along to offer an alternative to Stack Overflow.

**2. Eat Crow**
This one essentially boils down to everyone calming down.  Letting Stack Exchange do whatever it is they are going to do, and then find a way to make things work as good as possible.

This option is disgusting to those who are angry.  But to the general community (assuming that there is a community outside the Meta Community), is likely what will be chosen by default.

I imagine that there are also many gradient paths in-between these two extremes.

---

As I said in my first paragraph, I am a normalish user of Stack Overflow.  I have only been involved in what is going as a reader of events.  So I freely admit that I don't have any kind of insiders' perspective.

It is also possible that this will be very unpopular, but I felt it relevant and (for some unknown reason) I really wanted to say it.  So there it is.  This is just a discussion point.  No real question involved.

Comment: It was stated earlier that Meta consists of  [0.015% of the SO userbase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387680/how-was-the-number-of-015-of-meta-users-calculated)

Comment: related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513/lets-take-a-look-at-the-interaction-between-staff-and-the-power-users-of-the

Comment: The vast majority of the SO userbase  isn’t on Meta; that much is trivially true. However, what is often missed is that the vast majority of the SO userbase doesn’t care about the site. They land here via Google, get their answer, and then leave. They are, therefore, not really part of our community. What is missing, and needs to be re-understood at the highest levels, is that this core community is one of the site’s and the company’s biggest assets.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393155/ceos-2020-kickoff-blog-where-do-you-see-stack-overflow-going/393178#comment751542_393178

Comment: @CodyGray - And based on recent actions (and more importantly, inactions) I am saying that the leadership and owners of Stack Exchange Inc. have been convinced that this "core community" is not represented by the Meta Community.  Else why would they let the biggest asset to their company get so disgruntled?

Comment: Better question: what proportion of, say, the top 5% of answerers are part of the Meta community? All those great answers you come here to find have to come from somewhere, after all, and I've already seen several stories of top answerers being driven away from the site because of what's been happening.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery there are plenty of stats and queries of this kind in the answer linked from first rene's comment - i.e. roughly 12.5% of answers provided by users who also did something on meta. You should be able to tweak some queries to get the number you want. That could be forked to separate question as "top answeres" metric would need clarification (by number, by total votes, acceptance,...).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Please make this a question. It's interesting and if you don't I will.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to throw the meta.SE and the meta.SO community in the same "Meta community" bucket.

Comment: Not to distract from the conversation or take any validity away from your points; I just wanted to mention that it's hard for me to consider you, a 66k rep user who's been around since 2008, a "normalish" user.

Comment: @walen - That was the "ish" part.  I meant I am normal in that I use Stack Exchange to ask questions (which is where the vast majority of my rep comes from).  I don't do much else.  I don't engage in Meta often and I only occasionally answer.  I try to do a few review queue items now and then to "give back", but I am not involved much with Meta at large.

Comment: Option 3: leave.

Comment: I could not agree more. The vocal minority are a collective bag of temporary hot air. The management obviously know this. I am not sure what the question is, it is stating the obvious. But, well said.

Comment: It's easy to regard all vocal criticism as _hot air_. The magic thing that happens when you do is you discover there's no criticism at all. Everything you do is right. So many command economies discover this rather too late, to their cost. I'm sure Hans Christian Andersen wrote an instructive tale about the cost of muzzling and / or disregarding all criticism too. Robust individuals and organisations _invite_ constructive criticism (even when it is put bluntly) because they know *that's* what makes them better. Compare contemporary parliamentary democracies and the court of Louis XIV.

Answer (score 12):

One aspect not taken in to account by following the metrics alone is that the '0.015%' is likely to be the most active segment of the stack exchange user base. I would posit that this group represents the actual engaged users and volunteers without whom stack exchange would be just another messy internet message board.

From that POV, the meta community is really the key SE membership.

Comment: No positing required.  The "meta community" [contributes 12.5% of answers and about 20% of curation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387772/3063736).

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I think it is unhelpful and counter-productive to talk about the "Meta Community" as a separate entity from the wider, Stack Overflow Community.

People post here on Meta for a wide variety of reasons: "Why was my question closed?", "Why have I been review-banned?" and "Why was my suggested edit rejected?" are common questions from otherwise 'normal' Community Members.

Suggested tag-removals, bug-reports and other feature requests are common 'questions' from users who generally participate in Meta more frequently - but who, at the same time, are valued contributors to the main site. And let's not forget, answering questions is not the *only* good thing that the Community does: user-level moderation is *vital* to keep Stack Overflow in shape (not withstanding the Herculean efforts made by the *actual* Moderators).

The Meta site is also an excellent place for users to 'interact' (on some level) with those moderators, on a wide variety of matters. This is especially important (as I have learned from experience) for new(ish) users to improve their general contribution skills, and their understanding of how the Main Site works.

And then, of course, there is the "Evil and Toxic" (*sic*) faction! This comprises those (mostly well-established, high-rep) users who are *genuinely* concerned about the direction in which Stack Exchange Inc. seems to be taking the site - and the community, along with it. In recent months, several events (which I need not speak more of, here, yet) have caused this group of users to become more 'vocal' - and comments made, questions asked, and answers given by these folks have not generally gone down well with senior staff … hence the "Evil and Toxic" label.

So, to get back to your question. The "Meta Community" of which you speak would *seem* to refer to this last group. As to whether their points-of-view are acceptable, or whether their (suggested) actions are Good, Bad or Ugly - well, IMHO, that's up to individuals (be they 500K+ users, moderators, or just plain old 'normal(ish) users') to make their own decisions on their course of action. But what's wrong with having an open discussion about such issues so that, at the very least, folks can get a sense of what others in this **Great Community** feel about what's going on.

Just my four (Euro-) cents' worth.

Comment: I'm active on Meta for a long time, but my criticism would be that indeed the community here is not representative of all users of StackOverflow (which I would see primarily as the askers and answerers). An open discussion is nice and never hurts, but the voting on the open discussion, even though it's just (dis-)agreement, by a subset of all people gives results in just an echo chamber. In principle everyone can come here and take part, but in practice most do not. Are the scores on the contributions more or less meaningless in the end?

Comment: @Trilarion That fact that 'most users' don't actively participate doesn't, IMHO, make this a separate community. Maybe a sub-community? But many/most 'ordinary' users don't participate in Review Queues - does that make those who do a separate community? Meta is an optional extra.

Comment: I can agree with much of what you say.  I am  not trying to express my opinion in the concept of community vs meta community.  I was trying to say that the inactions of the Stack Exchange Inc owners show that THEY seem to not be worried about the angst expressed on Meta.  I think that THEY have been convinced (probably by leadership) that Meta anger is not really too impactful to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If I was to express my personal opinion it would be that they are treating this with way too much silence.  I think they need someone "the community" trusts (if any are left) to explain the overall plan and that, in the end, it will not be too different from what we are used to.  In plain, non-lawyer speak words.

Answer (score 5):

The Meta community is not representative of the whole Stack Overflow community, which includes all active users on StackOverflow.com maybe weighted by activity. It may not even include all of the core users. It's also a bit set in its ways, over the years, I'd say. This doesn't have to be bad, as it preserves knowledge about how things were done in the past, but it also may create barriers for newcomers.

It's a subgroup of the whole community and Meta allows it to organize itself. So far, so good. The crucial question is simply how much influence the Meta community really has? Completely side-lined, a sure seat at the table, or something in between? Jeff Atwood coined the "Listen to Your Community, But Don't Let Them Tell You What to Do." sentence, but what does listen actually include?

One could argue that the company is exactly following Jeff Atwood's advice now, they listen to what Meta says (update the CoC, the CEO posts) but they also decide for themselves what to do (restructure units, change rules, ..). It doesn't really look as if the Meta community is satisfied with some nebulous being listened to. It wants to be heard and exert influence. Because this influence is not really codified and probably can't, I think, this will always cause friction.

Please see also Ghostcat's answer to [Does Victoria Taylor's firing from Reddit in 2015 seem similar to recent events? What can Stack Exchange learn from it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342773/260073) where he argues that traditionally the relation between Meta community and company was done by trusted people but written down rules would be better.

I'm skeptic about the possibility of getting something in written form beyond marketing talk or empty promises, but I like the idea of Meta as something like a union/organization of the whole community open to everyone and acting for the good for everyone. I don't want to be just a member of the core user group, but I want that everyone can come here and voice his opinion, and that is actually still the case, even though I think that voting on Meta is broken, Meta is mostly an echo chamber of a few people and in general the company has much more power. Meta makes only sense for me if the idea is to represent potentially every user of Stack Overflow.

I don't think it's as black and white as depicted in this question. Between fully complying and total resistance there are probably some shades of reduced curation, downvoting orgies, less answering or fewer recommendations. Everyone uses his/her activity on the plattform as bargaining currency. If necessary we even collect money to sue the company, in case we think it has stepped over boundaries.

One last thing: There are bigger things happening than just September 2019. StackOverflow is in decline for many years and probably will continue to do so. Maybe because the original mission is partly accomplished or maybe because of something else. The company's ideas for a return to growth are not great in my opinion and the whole community (probably Meta community too) loses members every day. What will the new mission of Stack Overflow be now? If the company cannot answer that satisfactorily, maybe the Meta community (or nobody) could.

Comment: *"... or maybe because of something else"* - I would suggest that the something else is the (unstated) new goal of providing **free personal help** to everyone who asks, no matter how lazy they are, how newbie they are, etc.  So that they will keep coming back for more. That simply won't scale.  Experienced volunteers get fed up, inexperienced volunteers provide answers that are just guesses, questions go answered, user don't get the help they want and don't come back, frustration, complaints, downward spiral.

Comment: The root problem is that volunteers will only do things if they see some kind of reward in it for them.  Typically a good feeling for having helped someone.  But you don't get much of a good feeling from debugging yet another homework assignment, or paraphrasing the API documentation for someone who couldn't be bothered to look it up.

Comment: As long as there is programming, there will be a need for a site like this. If the goal was "to build a worse version of Wikipedia in Q&A format for frequently asked questions" then yeah, pretty much accomplished.

Comment: @Lundin Not sure how the two sentences are connected. Do you mean that there is a need for a worse version of Wikipedia in Q&A format?

Comment: No, I don't think the world has any use for that. So if that was the goal of the site, somebody was confused.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I'm an example of someone who does not consider the meta community representative of them *at all*.  I just come here every couple of weeks with a box of popcorn to watch the drama.  Then I go back to doing my work, which frequently involves getting help from easily the best Q&A community on the internet.  And no, I don't mean Quora, Experts Exchange or Spiceworks.

Edit to add serious part: My observations indicate that the meta community is almost exclusively from the "Answerers" camp.  There is no strong representation of the typical user, the asker.  In my opinion, from my perspective, this *does* provide a skewed "vocal minority".  Not that it justifies any actions by SOInc, it's just what I personally see.

Comment: eh, if you look through the avg user here, most *have* asked a decent number of questions in the past. It's no fault of ours if we've gotten to the point where we no longer need to ask due to learning how to leverage the vast amount of knowledge that has already been amassed. It simply makes us a different part of the community. Not a lesser, smaller, meaner, etc part, just a different part. One that many of the latest marketing material SOI has released (in the past 4 years) has been attacking.

Comment: I would like nothing more than to get more people into this place, where you no longer have to sit around waiting for someone to come along and help, where you know how to craft search terms to get what you want, or know how to interpret errors/stack traces/source code such that you can find the problems without having to rely on others... but I don't feel the current trend of providing quick no effort answers that are just good enough to fix the problem helps us (or anyone) get there.

Comment: Why do you consider the asker to be "the typical user"? The site works only because we have both, questions and answers. Furthermore, the askers wouldn't be here if they weren't getting answers. The experts who answer questions are what makes this site what it is, and the reason why it draws so much traffic. That they tend to be on Meta, where it's easy to gauge their experiences and opinions, is *extremely* handy.

Comment: I'm sure someone smarter than me can compile numbers on the # of unique askers and answerers.  But until I see that, I'll assume that more people come looking for help than come to provide it.

Comment: You do seem to follow the Meta trend of listing pronouns as a protest though. Either that, or you missed some prime drama about deleting the page you link to. And I don't know how I'd use that pronoun for you either. Other exciting trends included a wave of policing profile pages, including catching a very reasonable pronoun request which a mod says was just misunderstood :-(. Could you do me a favour and make any "preference" you're stating clearer? We've lost some good people who couldn't take this place anymore, so I'm not happy with the types of protest that could have been seen as taunts.