# Is Stack Overflow Contribution Activity Pareto Distributed?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I ask this question as SO contribution is largely a free decision: you can still keep using SO without making any contributions in return.

I'd expect Pareto statistics to apply in this case - it may even be heavily skewed, e.g. 95% of user contributions coming from 5% or less of contributing members.

But I'm just guessing. What's the real low-down here ?

Comment: That's not hard to figure out.  There are roughly 300000 user account pages on Stack Overflow.  You have to walk back to [page 50000](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=50000) or so to get to 31 rep.  Walking back to [page 10000](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=10000) gets you in the 500 rep range, and [page 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1000) gets you into the 6250 rep range.  At page 100, it's still only at about 47000 rep.  So yes, it's a parietal distribution.

Comment: Not to mention that most users of SO do not even have an account and just come here due to Google hits.

Comment: This great answer details out the activity by .015%: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387772

Comment: I was just thinking of those **freely** contributing only and what the profile of % of total contributions vs no. of contributors would look like. I am therefore excluding 'compelled contributors' like mods (paid & unpaid) as well as non-contributing users. You also have to define what a (useful) contribution is. It's not necessarily what another user may rate. Nor what a mod may find worthy because he/she is interested.Surely SO management have studied this ?

Comment: Yes, there is certainly a lot of contributions going on that doesn't give any reputation at all. Curation and most editing are included in those contributions. Then there is activity going on here on meta with some very good feature-requests. I don't think that's even remotely included in any statistics.

Comment: In what way do you think that a volunteer, community-elected moderator might be a "compelled contributor"? No moderators are paid anything.

Comment: @Trunk "Surely SO management have studied this ?" Yes, repeated times probably. However, it's not only the number crunching, it's also what conclusions to draw and the decisions how to weigh the different aspects of the data. It's just a guess, but in the past SO management might have over- or undervalued the importance of heavy contributing members. What I like about SO research is that they frequently also seem to ask themselves about the things that are not (so easily) visible in the data, like the attrition rate etc.

Comment: @CodyGray: Clearly, if I volunteer for mod duties on SO, I will feel compelled to do some moderating. This involves evaluation and often commenting - and occasionally up- or down-voting of new posts and comments. The latter are things that I might only do as a non-moderator if I happened to see those posts/comments by chance and found them interesting enough to react to.

Comment: @Scratte: That is how it should be. But most new comments and posts are read by mods these days, aren't they ? And it always seemed to me that some of these comments/posts - especially if they were made to older threads - were voted on by those same mods.But we are getting away from my main question here, i.e. the statistics of 'useful' contributors and how skewed they may be in terms of the proportion of all useful contributors. I accept SO has its own 'interests' and therefore preferences as regards user analysis. But all analysis must start with precise data. And no - I don't want the job !

Comment: I think it would make it easier if we were to refer to "mods" or "moderators" as the currently [20 elected moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) and to the others as "curators". Moderators do not come across most posts, because there are just too many of them. Curators come across post in curating queues or just by chance when browsing the site. All users are potential curators since everyone can either up/down-vote, flag and/or close-vote.

Comment: How would you measure that a user didn't upvote a post or didn't flag a comment, but just read it and moved on? Or made a useful comment as opposed to an non-useful one? I guess I'm asking: Am I contributing more if I answer a post but neglect to flag it as off-topic, than if I flag it without answering it, or comment to ask the author to edit their post with links to self-help?

Comment: @Scratte: Maybe by consideration of positive ratings of the contribution BOTH mods and other users, assuming the two types of ratings are stored separately.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously there are many ways to contribute to SO, but if we use "posts" as a proxy for "contribution activity" then... yeah... 1% of contributing members (<50K users) generate 99.8% of posts.

[SDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1258220/distribution-of-post-frequency-by-users#graph)
[image]
It *might* be [Pareto distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), if alpha is really high -- I'd have to output the csv and run a test -- but it's more extreme than the "80/20" rule people know as the "Pareto principle."

Comment: This is the first time I've used SEDE, so it's possible I'm missing a filter or something.  Please let me know!