# Notify the OP and those who starred a question of edits as well as new answers

Tags: feature-request, edits, meta, notifications, bookmarks

A star is intended to keep one updated on new answers. However, an edit that changes the meaning of an existing answer is effectively a new answer -- i.e. is also something that a person keeping an eye on the question wants to know.

When suggesting this, I'm primarily having the meta workflow in mind -- since meta posts are more likely to drastically change based on feedback in the course of discussion.

So maybe this feature should be primarily considered for (or at least first tried out on) metas.

Comment: Interim search query for activity on starred questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=infavorites%3Amine+is%3Aq+answers%3A1..

Comment: "*A star is intended to keep one updated on new answers.*" Is it? I thought it was just a bookmarking system, a built-in way to keep track of interesting quesitons. If I start getting notifications every time someone does anything to any of my starred questions, I'm going to remove all of those stars.

Comment: @NicolBolas Whatever is the case, the star notifies you of new answers -- so it's not _just_ a bookmarking system.

Comment: Not an inbox notification, @Nicol, but rather a badge on the "Favorites" tab of your profile. It's always been implemented that way. Very discreet and low-impact, but there if you want to go looking for it. I agree that I would very much *not* want inbox notifications for this. I get far too many of those already.

Comment: Perhaps you could _request_ inbox notifications for edits to an answer on a per-question basis? And maybe only edits by the OP of the answer - ones that would change its meaning?

Comment: **NB** it's a known problem that no one seems to know exactly what the notification icon on the profile's favorites tab indicates. New answers? New comments? Edits to answers? Edits to the question? State changes? Something else?

Answer (score 21):

Hmm? Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the behaviour you're asking for is already implemented for those who've starred a question. Right now at the top of my favourites I've got this:

[image: Screenshot showing a highlighted entry in my Favorites tab]

which, if I click through, I see is alerting me to an edit to an answer:

[image: Screenshot showing the edit described]

I suppose you're right that OPs don't get alerted of these same edits, which is kind of perverse, but starrers do.

Comment: I must say this made me confuse, I saw the question asked 12 hours ago and then Answered on Apr 19 '18. Then I didn't noticed your name after carefully checking the answer and noticed it was an image of an answer inside your answer.

Comment: @Frakcool Yeah, screenshots of Stack Exchange posts on Meta are a natural source of confusion. I guess I could've added a border or something to mitigate the potential, but I'm lazy.

Comment: I wasn't notified of edits to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385143/648265 -- an answer to my question. I presumed that a star must produce a strict subset of notifications that an OP would receive so pulled them together...

Comment: And I was speaking about inbox notifications, not whatever you see if you manually open your profile.

Answer (score 7):

> A star is intended to keep one updated on new answers.

Your premise is flawed. That may be why *you* use stars, but that sure isn't why I use them.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580/161554

I use stars to bookmark things that I find interesting or useful, or potentially useful in the future. I sure as heck don't want to get inbox notifications when they're edited or new answers are given. I don't even check that tab on my profile unless I'm specifically trying to find something that I had starred in the past.

I find it hard to believe that 19 out of 22 people (the current up/down votes on this question) want inbox notifications on questions that they starred.

Comment: The text on your link: _"Marking a question as a favorite basically says that a particular user feels like watching that question."_ This can be interpreted very broadly but the fact remains that a star updates you on new answers, whether you use that or not.

Comment: _"I find it hard to believe that... people... want inbox notifications"_ -- they didn't specify otherwise... And I did mark the question with [meta-tag:notifications]. If you think the question post is confusing and prone to misinterpretation, you can clarify it.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Yes and the way it updates you currently is more than enough

Comment: Also note that I'm primarily suggesting this for metas. On a main site, I agree that drastic changes to an answer are rare and very much frowned upon, so most edits are going to be minor.

Comment: "Favorites" have always been a weird feature without a single clear use-case. They can be a way of *watching* questions for updates, a list of questions you intend to take action on later, a list of canonical questions that you frequently refer to, or just a kind of weird parallel upvote system that pushes questions towards the Stellar Question badge. The diversity of use-cases means that changes designed to make one case work better may harm another, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

An analgous website feature worth thinking about might be Wikipedia watchlists. They have the same star UI as favourites here, and they allow the following use cases:

1. **Bookmark** things that are interesting or useful. To find something again, users typically go to their Special:EditWatchlist page, which contains a list of all the articles they've watchlisted.
2. **Stay up to date** on recent changes to articles (but without bombarding users with unwanted notifications). To do this, users typically go to Special:Watchlist, which contains a most-recent-first sorted list of article changes, including, most importantly:

   1. the name of the user who made the most recent change,
   2. the change's edit message,
   3. and a direct link to the change diff.

Two main differences between Wikipedia's watchlist and Stack Exchange's favourites list:

1. On Wikipedia, users can get to their watchlist with a single click from any page via a link at the top right. On Stack Exchange, users need to (1) click profile and then (2) click favourites. That's an extra step, so this page probably isn't visited as frequently.
2. On Wikipedia, the changes contain a lot more detail and more direct links to relevant information.

Example watchlist screenshot: (pretty dense and verbose, but eh)

[image: watchlist screenshot]

So one idea might be to just make the favourites page more visible so that you can visit it more frequently. You know, using polling instead of interrupts.

Wikipedia has an option to turn on email notifications every time a page on your watchlist is updated, so that's also an option...