# i.stack.imgur.com is down

Tags: bug, status-norepro, imgur

The following URLs all yield 502 errors for me:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUYaH.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkIZm.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYmrw.png?s=32&g=1
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/

I was alerted to this by [another user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386723/notify-the-op-and-those-who-starred-a-question-of-edits-as-well-as-new-answers#comment708754_386735).

Update: seems to be back up.

Comment: I think it's actually cloudflare that's experiencing problems.

Comment: The images work for me and you're using HTTP instead of HTTPS in your last link. But I wonder what SE should do about a third-party provider having a downtime?

Comment: I just noticed this, some images were working, others weren't (maybe some working was due to caching)

Comment: They all load for me currently, so either a transient issue or a localised CDN issue, where a specific (set of) access point(s) is down.

Comment: @Tom Seems fickle - my face briefly reappeared for me, then was a 502 again when I started writing this comment, then yielded the custom "hair on fire" imgur error message, and now is back. As for what SE should do - in the short term, probably nothing. But I figure it's worth having these Meta questions to document the outages and let people know why they're seeing broken images.

Comment: @Tom: nothing, if the downtime is transient, or start looking for an alternative provider if the problem is systemic. Just like any engineering issue. The web is distributed, so sometimes something breaks for a bit. Nothing major here.

Comment: [I have the same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330388/295232) and I sometimes get a nice "Imgur is over capacity!" error page.

Comment: It's hit-or-miss right now. [Cloudflare's status page says they're looking into issues](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/)

Comment: I thought *i.stack.imgur.com* is a special instance for Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Chr that’s correct.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt it can still run on Cloudflare. Imgur itself didn't appear to be affected though.

Comment: @Zoe most of imgur runs via fastly these days. I suspect that the SO domain just hasn’t transitioned yet. (No actual evidence other than that imgur [explicitly lists their fastly CDN status on their status page](https://status.imgur.com/)).

Comment: @Tom What they should do is cash in on that sweet SLA money, they probably have one for their instance of imgur. The downtime was probably too short, though.

Comment: The service is running right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Cloudflare Status](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/incidents/tx4pgxs6zxdr):

> Cloudflare has implemented a fix for this issue and is currently monitoring the results.
>
> We will update the status once the issue is resolved.

So hopefully this is working again.

---

Update 2019-07-03 00:30 UTC:

An email was sent to Cloudflare customers with the following information:

> Dear Cloudflare Customer,
>
> Today at approximately 13:42 UTC we experienced a global service disruption that affected most Cloudflare traffic for 27 minutes.
>
> The issue was triggered by a bug in a software deploy of the Cloudflare Web Application Firewall (WAF) which resulted in a CPU usage spike globally, and 502 errors for our customers. To restore global traffic we temporarily disabled certain WAF capabilities, removed the underlying software bug, then verified and re-enabled all WAF services.
>
> We’re deeply sorry about how this disruption has impacted your services. Our engineering teams continue to investigate this issue and we will be sharing detailed incident report(s) on the Cloudflare blog.
>
> ~The Cloudflare Team

---

There is also [a blog post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-outage/) with more details regarding the specific cause of this outage:

> The intent of these new rules was to improve the blocking of inline JavaScript that is used in attacks. These rules were being deployed in a simulated mode...
>
> Unfortunately, one of these rules contained a regular expression that caused CPU to spike to 100% on our machines worldwide. This 100% CPU spike caused the 502 errors that our customers saw...
>
> We were seeing an unprecedented CPU exhaustion event, which was novel for us as we had not experienced global CPU exhaustion before...
>
> At 1402 UTC we understood what was happening and decided to issue a ‘global kill’ on the WAF Managed Rulesets, which instantly dropped CPU back to normal and restored traffic. That occurred at 1409 UTC.
>
> We then went on to review the offending pull request, roll back the specific rules, test the change to ensure that we were 100% certain that we had the correct fix, and re-enabled the WAF Managed Rulesets at 1452 UTC.

Comment: We decided to use a regex to work around a potential JavaScript vulnerability. This left us with two problems...

Comment: Yay, sounds like someone learned about [catastrophic backtracking](https://regular-expressions.mobi/catastrophic.html). The hard way.